# Coffescript don't work when it is inserted via document.wrileln

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

My code is inserted into html via this code.

1) widget_demo.html.erb

```
<script src="//<%= request.host_with_port %>/assets/widget/widget_code.js"></script>
```

2) widget_code.js.erb

```
document.writeln("<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js'></script>");
document.writeln("<script src='//<%= Rails.env.production? ? 'alpha.uncoverage.com' : 'localhost:3000' %>/assets/widget/widget_code_internal.js'></script>");
```

3) Depending one widget_code_internal file extension - it works/doesn't work.

```
widget_code_internal.js - works
widget_code_internal.js.coffee - doesn't
```

I guess it's related with some coffee processing in Rails. But I do not what's wrong.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Browsers don't know what CoffeeScript is, you have to translate it to JavaScript before the browser can do anything with it.

Comment: and this translation can be asset precompilation. You should reference to compiled version, either using rails' `rake assets:precompile`  or other tools